# Why in stdbool.h are used integers and not unsigned ones?

Tags: c, performance, boolean, c99, unsigned

In `stdbool.h`, `true` and `false` are simply integers. Why not unsigned? Is there performance motivations?

Comment: Does it matter?

Comment: `int` is kinda the "default" datatype, I do not believe that there is a deeper reason than that.

Comment: Also if we had `#define true ((_Bool)1)`, then it wouldn't be valid in an `#if` directive.

Comment: @aschepler Note: `#define true 1u` would be fine in an `#if` directive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the type `int` for the values `false` and `true` makes them agree with the type and set of values resulting from the logical negation operator (`!`), the relational operators (`<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`), the equality operators (`==`, `!=`), the logical AND operator (`&&`), and the logical OR operator (`||`), all of which produce the value 0 or 1 of type `int`.

Also, if `true` was defined as `1u`, then `int minust = -true;` would initialize `minust` to an implementation-defined value (or raise an implementation-defined signal), rather than initializing `minust` to the value `-1`. The compiler may issue a warning. This is because `1u` is of type `unsigned int`, `-1u` has the value `UINT_MAX`, and `UINT_MAX` cannot be represented by an `int`.

I realize the `-true` argument is a bit weak. The point I am trying to get across is that defining the `false` and `true` constants to be of type `unsigned int`, rather than the type of the purely numeric values 0 and 1 (i.e. `int`), would impose restrictions (unwarranted restrictions in my view) of what you can do with those constants.

Comment: Why could you want a `int minust = -true;` in your code? IMHO `-true` makes no sense, what you want is `! true`.

Comment: @MarcoSulla It's just an example.

Comment: @MarcoSulla: Another reason is consistency with types produced by various operators. See the third paragraph I just added to my answer.

Comment: Yes, we arrived to the [same conclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58622239/why-in-stdbool-h-are-used-integers-and-not-unsigned-ones/58623323#comment103556595_58622992) :)

Comment: I can accept your answer, if you remove the first part :P

Comment: @MarcoSulla: I'd rather keep the first part, but I've rearranged the parts to make it the last part, more of an aside.

Comment: Well, IMHO if you get a `-true` in a code, you're authorized to slap the coder :D Anyway I accept your answer :)

Comment: The first part is good UV. The 2nd `-true` example is weak.  Similar weak argument could be made for `~false` favoring `unsigned` - it's always well defined.  As `int` can lead to troubles with archaic sign-magnitude, ones' complement.  `~false` is still false with ones' complement.

Comment: @chux I've added another paragraph to try and explain what I was trying to get at with my somewhat weak example.

Answer (score 3):

Both true and false are '#defined' to 0, 1. As such, they are not signed or unsigned, just token. They will be 'typed' on assignment, comparison, usually at no run-time cost.

```
bool b = true ;
unsigned int uv = true ;
int sv = true ;
```

Both will take same time to executed

Comment: And there's no performance difference in comparison (`1 == 1` vs `1U` == `1U`)? What about `if (1)` vs `if (1U)`? Have you some bench?

Comment: You can generate asm file (gcc -S). You will see that it generates the same code for both signed and signed values - the compiler skip the test, as this is a constant expression.

Comment: Mmmmh.... I just have a simple question now: `1U == 1U` what does return, an `int` or an `unsigned int`?

Comment: @MarcoSulla The result of `==` operator has the type `int`.

Comment: "As such, they are not signed or unsigned"  --> Disagree.   `true` is specified as a "integer constant 1".  An integer constant  of 1 in code has type `int`.  C11 §6.4.4.1 5

Answer (score 0):

Once in one of my lectures my professor said that bool implementation in C as integers was dedicated to electric rules. 1 electricity flows, 0 no signal. So 1-true 0 false

Comment: Apart the fact that your professor's affirmation is highly questionable, `0U` does not means zero? :D

Comment: I meant more about the reference system in which we consider the voltage as the zero level of the system and the higher voltage is an 1 :')